# set focus after update or delete row in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in my project when I add new row for first time it will default focus on first cell , then I delete row or update row or refresh row it will not focus on first cell anymore after I add new row again.
Here is my code:

```
departmentGrid = $("#departmentcfggrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "DepartmentName",
            title: DepartmentConstants.lbDepartmentName,
            width: 250,
            headerTemplate: "<span id='DepartmentName_MandatoryTooltip'></span>" + DepartmentConstants.lbDepartmentName,
            editor: function (container, options) {
                //Create an input element
                var input = $('<input id="DepartmentNameTextBox" placeholder="' + DepartmentConstants.lbDepartmentName + '" class="k-input k-textbox" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '">');
                input.attr("name", options.field);
                input.attr("maxlength", 100);
                //Append it to the container
                input.appendTo(container);
                input.keyup(function (e) {
                    if (fqtt_CheckKeyCodeForInput(e.keyCode)) {
                        var pickupvalue = $(this).val();
                        var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
                        //Set value for checkbox
                        var dataItem = departmentGrid.dataItem(currentRow);
                        dataItem.set('DepartmentName', pickupvalue);
                        fqtt_ControlButtonGridDepartment();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        ]
```

Here is add new row event:

```
$("#departmentcfggrid .k-grid-add-department").click(function () {
    if (fqtt_ValidationAddNewDepartmentsInGridData()) {
        departmentGrid.addRow();
        $("#DepartmentNameTextBox").focus();
        fqtt_ControlButtonGridDepartment();
    }

});
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: duplicate id's could be your issue.

Comment: there is nowhere duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

var view = this.dataSource.view();

```
    if(view.length>0){
        this.select(this.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + view[0].uid + "']"));
    }
```

in place of $("#DepartmentNameTextBox").focus();
It worked for me.